# Add a word in end of each line starting with > in a file using unix command

Tags: linux, command

I have a text file containing ~25000 fasta format sequences, I want to add a word in end of each line starting with > .

Comment: `sed '/^>/s/$/ your_word/' infile > outfile`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether or not the same word has to be appended to matching lines (those starting with `>`), so I assumed the simplest case. The `sed` below adds " PLOP" at the end of all lines starting with `>` :

```
tmpFile=$(mktemp)
echo -e 'hello world\n>FASTA sequence\nhello again' > "$tmpFile"
echo 'BEFORE :'
cat "$tmpFile"
sed -ri '/^>/ s/^(.*)$/\1 PLOP/' "$tmpFile"
echo 'AFTER :'
cat "$tmpFile"
[ -f "$tmpFile" ] && rm "$tmpFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with *awk*

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ "^>") { $0=$0" added" }} {print $0}' list
```

or *sed*

```
sed -E "s|^>(.+)$|>\1 added|" list
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however every appended words come in new line, I need in one whole line though.
Output file:
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27=TIR_ECO27
;DBGWAS_specific_tag=[uniprot]                (appended words)

Desired output::
>sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27=TIR_ECO27;DBGWAS_specific_tag=[uniprot]

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you need, could you please edit your question and describe the expected result?